# Jquery not updating .val first time round?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been doing the booking form on this website here. http://offline.raileisure.com/

if you fill in the booking form on the right hand side.. click extras and add some extras

click get price to get the popup window...

You see where is says "Base Accomodation Price comes to £"

Well the first time it doesn't bring the price up (although it is setting the $('#bpriceinput').val(data);

if you click away to disappear the popup and click get price again. "Base Accomodation Price comes to £" now has the price...

IT just doesn't want to appear first time... is it because i am updating too close the the window popping up ??

I am baffled and spent 2 hours on this silly bug

Any help will be hugely appreciated

Thanks

Lee

Comment: I actually get a � instead of the pound token.

Comment: I also got a correct answer the first time and then NAN the second time (not using the same config). You either have a race condition (probably due to your ajax call) or you're trying to do something invalid (like adding a string). I noticed that the server response (ajax call) was 'n/a' one one ocassion - why would this be happening?

Comment: strange, i will fix that after this big bug :-)

Comment: Yes some of the dates are set incorrectly which brings the Nan, thats cool i know about that, i just need to sort the dates in the database... again something i will do after this big bug

Comment: For me is everthing OK (FF 5.0 MacOs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line 546 `$('#extrasinfo').html($('#extrasinfo').html() + "<br><br>Total for Extras comes to £" + extras + "<br>Base Accomodation Price comes to £" + $('#bpriceinput').val());`

Is fired before the callback of your POST request has finished. You should add this line inside the callback.
Also, the "Get Price" button stays disabled until you have selected everything and the clicked on the calendar again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the AJAX call is made and that's asynchronous. In the meantime you're setting the 'comes to ...' text, but the data isn't available yet.

The second time, the data from the first time is available and shows that one, so it's still not correct.

```
    $.post("getprice.php", { unit: $('input[name=property]:checked').val() , date: $('#car').val() + $('#smh').val(), duration: $('input[name=duration]:checked').val()  } ,function(data){

        $('#bpriceinput').val(data);

        $('div[name=price]').html("Total Price: �" + ((parseFloat(data, 10) + extras)).toFixed(2));

        $('#btotalpriceinput').val(((parseFloat(data, 10) + extras)).toFixed(2));

    }); // <-- what if you move this line to the end of the calculation (i.e. line 551)
```

Comment: Agree with pimvdb. I would suggest adding a callback on success on the post function before processing the rest.

Comment: tried that... it screws up big time, it actually stops the total price from working :-( if what you say is true then the total price wouldn't work but it is... the total price uses the base price

Comment: @jen - not sure how to do that, or if needed... i thought the commands inside the function do run after the post has run ?

Comment: @Lee: You set the total price in the callback when the AJAX is complete don't you? That should work fine. However the base price you're calculating before the data has arrived.